# How to compute sum of binomial more efficiently?

Tags: matlab, performance, time, vectorization, mex

I must calculate an equation as follows:

[image]
where `k1,k2` are given. I am using MATLAB to compute `P`. I think I have a correct implementation for the above equation. However, my implementation is so slow. I think the issue is from binomial coefficient. From the equation, could I have an efficient way to speed up the time? Thank all.

For `k1=150; k2=150; D=200;`, it takes **11.6 seconds**

```
function main
warning ('off');
  function test_binom()
      k1=150; k2=150; D=200; P=0;
      for i=0:D-1
          for j=0:i
              if (i-j>k2||j>k1) 
                  continue;
              end
              P=P+nchoosek(k1,j)*nchoosek(k2,i-j)/nchoosek((k1+k2),i);          
          end 
      end
  end
f = @()test_binom(); 
timeit(f)
end
```

Update: For measure time, I found that nchoosek is the reason for large computational time. Hence, I rewrite the function as follows

```
function re=choose(n, k)
    if (k == 0)
        re=1;
    else
        re=(n * choose(n - 1, k - 1)) / k;
    end
end
```

Now, the computational time is reduced as 0.25 second. Is has any better way?

Comment: Your code doesn't work because there is no summation. Also, what's with the `function main` and `warning off`???

Comment: I agree with @dasdingonesin: there should be a `P=P+...`  in there. Also, why did you tag this with `[mex]`? Did you try Jan Simon's [`VChooseK`](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/26190-vchoosek)? Moreover, what do you mean by "I think the issue is from binomial coefficient" - there's no place for guessing - run the profiler and see.

Comment: Sorry. I mistook it. The warning off is used to turn off the warning of choose when k is big. I write the issue is binominal coefficient because it spends a lot of time to compute

Comment: @Dev-iL hahah, agreed about the profiler, but you need to gauge your audience and pick your battles, man :p

Comment: I also tag mex because I think it can use to speed up some Matlab function. I saw VChooseK function. Is it similar with nchoosek?I ran the profile and saw that nchoosek spends a lot of time

Comment: I confirmed that VchooseK does not work for above purpose. It has error "Output would be too large."

Comment: not so sure about the if part... A: the picture says **i** >k1 but your formual says **j** >k1 and B: why go for the continue if you could just switch the condition and the go straight for the statement

Comment: Right. It must be j. I used both condition to make the combinations are valid

Comment: The bigger problem here is that your calculations are wildly inaccurate. Those warnings that you're ignoring are telling you that your floating-point values don't have the precision to hold the values you're trying to calculate. `nchoosek(150,75) ≈ 1e44`, which is way beyond double precision. I can speed up your code, but I don't think the results will mean much.

Comment: @beaker: You are right when the n and k are very big. it may effect to result. However, it does not matter because I just consider the probability `P`. Someone suggested me to use the mex file. I used it and it can speed up 3x

Comment: @EBH 's answer is very efficient, However I modified it to prevent repeated evaluation So it becomes very very efficient. http://rextester.com/LTMMV64126. please accept his answer!

Comment: I will accept his answer. Do you want to update anything about the loop condition based on my updated question before(Let saw it in comment of your answer)

Comment: Take a look a my edit, it's extremely optimized now...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can vectorize all the process and it will make it super-fast without any need for mex.

First the `nchoosek` function:

```
function C = nCk(n,k)
% use smaller k if available
k(k>n/2) = n-k(k>n/2);
k = k(:);
kmat = ones(numel(k),1)*(1:max(n-k));
kmat = kmat.*bsxfun(@le,kmat,(n-k));
pw = bsxfun(@power,kmat,-1./(n-k));
pw(kmat==0) = 1;
kleft = ones(numel(k),1)*(min(k):n);
kleft = kleft.*bsxfun(@gt,kleft,k);
t = bsxfun(@times,kleft,prod(pw,2));
t (kleft==0) = 1;
C = prod(t,2);
end
```

Then `beta` and `P` computation:

```
function P = binomial_coefficient(k1,k2,D)
warning ('off','MATLAB:nchoosek:LargeCoefficient');
i_ind = nonzeros(triu(ones(D,1)*(1:D)))-1;
j_ind = nonzeros(tril(ones(D,1)*(1:D+1)).')-1;
valid = ~(i_ind-j_ind>=k2 | j_ind>=k1);
i_ind = i_ind(valid);
j_ind = j_ind(valid);
beta = @(ii,jj) nCk(k1,jj).*nCk(k2,ii-jj)./nCk((k1+k2),ii);
b = beta(i_ind,j_ind);
P = sum(b(:));
end
```

and execution time drops from **10.674** to  **0.49696** seconds.

**EDIT:**

Taking the idea of @rahnema1, I managed to make this even faster, using a table for all unique `nCk` computations, so none of them will be done more than once. Using the same `nCk` function from above, this is how the new `binomial_coefficient` function will look:

```
function P = binomial_coefficient(k1,k2,D)
warning ('off','MATLAB:nchoosek:LargeCoefficient');
i_ind = nonzeros(triu(ones(D,1)*(1:D)))-1;
j_ind = nonzeros(tril(ones(D,1)*(1:D+1)).')-1;
valid = ~(i_ind-j_ind>=k2 | j_ind>=k1);
i_ind = i_ind(valid);
j_ind = j_ind(valid);
ni = numel(i_ind);
all_n = repelem([k1; k2; k1+k2],ni); % all n's to be used in thier order
all_k = [j_ind; i_ind-j_ind; i_ind]; % all k's to be used in thier order
% get all unique sets of 'n' and 'k':
sets_tbl = unique([all_n all_k],'rows');
uq_n = unique(sets_tbl(:,1));
nCk_tbl = zeros([max(all_n) max(all_k)+1]);
% compute all the needed values of nCk:
for s = 1:numel(uq_n)
    curret_n = uq_n(s);
    curret_k = sets_tbl(sets_tbl(:,1)==curret_n,2);
    nCk_tbl(curret_n,curret_k+1) = nCk(curret_n,curret_k).';
end
beta = @(ii,jj) nCk_tbl(k1,jj+1).*nCk_tbl(k2,ii-jj+1)./nCk_tbl((k1+k2),ii+1);
b = beta(i_ind,j_ind);
P = sum(b(:));
end
```

and now, when it takes only **0.01212** second to run, it's not just super-fast code, it's a [flying-talking-super-fast](https://youtu.be/KLEP0fN8axk) code!

Comment: Thank for your method. It takes about 0.5 sec, comparison with 0.3 sec. in my code and 0.1 sec for mex code

Comment: well, I didn't notice that you reduced the time to 0.3 sec. I didn't try, but you may convert this to mex and see if there's improvement.

Comment: Thank you. I think main issue is from combination. We are trying to reduce it

Comment: As I suspected, converting this to mex only makes it slower (x3). I would try combining the advice from the previous answer _"prevent repeated evaluation of the function"_ with this vectorization.

Comment: 1+ .very interesting. I modified your code to prevent repeated evaluation: http://rextester.com/LTMMV64126 . please update your answer.

Comment: Very well! For some reason I get an error on `tblrep = tblrep(bck_idx);` that says _Index exceeds matrix dimensions_ when I run it on my MATLAB. Let me debug it tomorrow, and I'll update the answer.

Comment: @rahnema1 take a look at my edit, same idea as you suggested, just more simple code.

Comment: It is a super fast code. It is faster than mex code about 7 times. I just try to understand your code by a little modification (adding a multiple with A and 0.5^i term, where A is vector matrix `1xD`) in the beta function  as `beta_i,j= \sum_i \sum_j (A(i)* 0.5^i*nchoosek(k1,i)...)`. which line have I change in your code?

Comment: @user8430 assuming `A` is 1-by-`D+1` (row vector), you only need to change `beta` to: `beta = @(ii,jj) A(ii+1).*(0.5.^ii).'.*(nCk_tbl(k1,jj+1).*nCk_tbl(k2,ii-jj+1)./nCk_tbl((k1+k2),ii+1));`. Note that you cannot use `0` as index, so I define `A` to be in length `D+1`, and using `A(ii+1)` inside the function.

Answer (score 3):

You can save results of nchoosek to a table to prevent repeated evaluation of the function, also an implementation of binomial coefficients provided:

```
%binomial coefficients
function nk=nchoosek2(n, k)
    if n-k > k
        nk = prod((k+1:n) .* prod((1:n-k).^ (-1/(n-k))));
    else
        nk = prod((n-k+1:n) .* prod((1:k).^ (-1/k)) ) ;
    end
end
%function to store and retrieve results of nchoosek to/from a table
function ret = choose (n,k, D, K1, K2)
    persistent binTable = zeros(max([D+1,K1+K2+1]) , D+1);
    if binTable(n+1,k+1) == 0
        binTable(n+1,k+1) = nchoosek2(n,k);
    end
    ret = binTable(n+1,k+1);
end

function P = tst()
    P=0;k1=150; k2=150; D=200; P=0;
    choose(1,0,D,k1,k2);
    for i = 0:D-1
        for j = j=max(i - k2 , 0):min (i,k1-1)
            P=P+choose(k1,j)*choose(k2,i-j)/choose((k1+k2),i);
        end
    end
end
```

Your code with nchoosek2 compared with this:
[online demo](http://rextester.com/NBRGD26428)

Comment: Thanks. Could you explain how you can choose the range `max(i-k2,0):min(i,k1)` for `j` from above my equation. It is correct and makes the code more efficient

Comment: two conditions should be met:
1. j should be lower than k1
since j variates from 0 to i-1 we should change range of j to variate from 0 to a number that is lower than k1 ,so j can variate from 0 to k1-1,but since it is possible that i-1 to be lower than k1 so we take min (i-1,k1-1) as the upper limit of variation of j.

Comment: 2. i-j should be lower than k2
to meed this condition we should look at the range of variation of both i and j and see where k2 becomes lower or equal to i-j.

Comment: if value of i is smaller than value of j then i-j becomes negative and alway lower than k2 so it is impossible that i-j becomes greater than k2 for lower values of i. Also to i-j becomes greater than and equal to k2 it is needed to values of j to be low.So we should set a limit for low values of j so those values of j that make i-j greater than and equal to k2 do not included in range of values of j, so we may set this limlit to i - (k2 -1).

Comment: but since it is possible that becomes negative we take max(i - (k2 -1), 0) as the lower limit of j.
example:
 lower limit of j is i -(k2-1);
 test if i-j< k2:
 i - {i - (k2-1))};
 = k2-1  that always is lower than k2!
  test next j that is (i -(k2-1) +1) to be lower than k2:
   i - (i -(k2-1) +1)
   = k2 -2 that always is lower than k2!
 ...

Comment: @user8430 I edited the answer ,because the answer was based on your code that limits of i and j in it is not correct so changed the code to be based on the formule

Comment: OMG. I have check my condition again. It has a minor wrong. It must be `i-j>k2 and j>k1`, instead of `i-j>=k2 and j>=k1`. These conditions aim to make these combinations are valid. With edited condition. Do you need change any range of loop `j`?

Comment: change max(i - k2, 0):min (i-1,k1). in the formula  should "i" variate from 0 to D-1 or 0 to D? .and for j variate form 0 to i or i-1? Answer updated.

Comment: Thank rahnema. The i change from 0 to D-1 and j is from 0 to i-1. The above conditions are correct. Finally, we got j change from `max(i - k2, 0):min (i-1,k1)` or `max(i - k2, 0):min (i-1,k1-1)`. Because in your updated answer it is `max(i - k2, 0):min (i-1,k1-1)`

Comment: if 0 change form 0 to D-1 please update the question specially the image should be changed. with this conditions you can change the code this way: for i = 0:D-1; for j = j=max(i - k2 , 0):min (i-1,k1-1); P=P+choose(k1,j)*choose(k2,i-j)/choose((k1+k2),i); end; end;

Answer (score 1):

[rahnema1's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39133579/1377097) answer has a very good approach: create a table of values that you generate once and access later (as well as some other clever optimizations).

One thing I would change is the way the binomial coefficients are calculated. If you look at calculating the factorials for `nchoosek(n, k)` and `nchoosek(n, k+1)`, you're recalculating `n!` both times, and for `k+1`, you're recalculating `k!` and multiplying it by `k+1`. (Similarly for `(n-k)!`.)

Rather than throw away the computations each time, we can iteratively compute `nchoosek(n, k+1)` based on the value of `nchoosek(n, k)`.

```
function L=combList(n, maxk)
% Create a vector of length maxk containing
%   [nchoosek(n, 1), nchoosek(n, 2), ..., nchoosek(n, maxk)]
% Note: nchoosek(n, 0) == nchoosek(n, n) == 1

assert(maxk<=n, 'maxk must be less than or equal to n');

L = zeros(1,maxk);
L(1) = n;                    % nchoosek(n, 1) == n
for k = 2:maxk
   L(k) = L(k-1)*(n-k+1)/k;
end
```

In your program, you would just create 3 lists for `k1`, `k2`, and `k1+k2` with the appropriate limits, and then index into those lists to generate the sums.