# How to convert a recursive function to mex code?

Tags: matlab, mex

I have a recursive function choose in MATLAB code as follows:

```
   function nk=choose(n, k)
        if (k == 0)
            nk=1;
        else
            nk=(n * choose(n - 1, k - 1)) / k;
        end
    end
```

The code is used to compute the combination between n and k. I want to speed up it by using mex code. I tried to write a mex code as

```
double choose(double* n, double* k)
{
   if (k==0) 
        return 1;
   else
        return (n * choose(n - 1, k - 1)) / k;
}

void mexFunction(int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[], int nrhs, const mxArray *prhs[])
{
    double *n, *k, *nk;
    int mrows, ncols;
    plhs[0] = mxCreateDoubleMatrix(1,1, mxREAL);
    /* Assign pointers to each input and output. */
    n = mxGetPr(prhs[0]);    
    k = mxGetPr(prhs[1]);
    nk = mxGetPr(plhs[0]);
    /* Call the recursive function. */
    nk=choose(n,k);
}
```

However, it does not work. Could you help me to modify the mex code which can implement the above MATLAB code? Thanks

Comment: Well, in programming languages like C, recursion is usually not the programming tool of choice to achieve great speeds – each level of recursion demands that you store the stack, arrange for arguments passed to your function, call the function, let the function do it's thing and in the end bubble up values, restoring the stack at each step... the overhead is substantial for simple functions.

So, given that your problem doesn't *dictate* you do this recursively, *don't do it recursively*.

Comment: I think my implementation in mex code was wrong. Could you help me to fix it

Comment: No: the point is that no matter how correct you implement your mex, it misses the point.

Comment: Maybe he is trying to implement an example of inefficient programming techniques as an example of "things to avoid when programming".

Comment: Actually, [he has](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39118818/how-to-compute-sum-of-binomial-more-efficiently) an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). "It does not work" is not a great problem description, either.

Comment: you could do this, maybe, with `matlabFunction()`, but as the rest of the people say, do not use recursion in here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code fixes your C mex implementation.
The problem is not the recursion of course...
Your code uses pointers instead of values (in C it's important to use pointers only in the right places).

You can use Matlab build in function: `nchoosek`
See: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/nchoosek.html

The following code works:

```
//choose.c

#include "mex.h"

double choose(double n, double k)
{
    if (k==0) 
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        return (n * choose(n - 1, k - 1)) / k;
    }
}


void mexFunction(int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[], int nrhs, const mxArray *prhs[])
{
    double *n, *k, *nk;
    int mrows, ncols;
    plhs[0] = mxCreateDoubleMatrix(1,1, mxREAL);
    /* Assign pointers to each input and output. */
    n = mxGetPr(prhs[0]);    
    k = mxGetPr(prhs[1]);
    nk = mxGetPr(plhs[0]);

    /* Call the recursive function. */
    //nk=choose(n,k);
    *nk = choose(*n, *k);
}
```

Compile it within Matlab:
`mex choose.c`

Execute:
`choose(10,5)`
`ans =`

`252`

It is not inefficient implementation...
I am helping fixing your implementation, to be used as "inefficient example".

---

Measure execution of rahnema1's implementation:
tic;n = 1000000;k = 500000;nk = prod((k+1:n) .* prod((1:n-k).^ (-1/(n-k))));toc
Elapsed time is 0.022855 seconds.

Measure execution of choose.mexw64 implementation:
tic;n = 1000000;k = 500000;nk = choose(1000000, 500000);toc
Elapsed time is 0.007952 seconds.
(took a little less time than prod((k+1:n) .* prod((1:n-k).^ (-1/(n-k))))).

Measure Matlab recursion, getting error (even for n=700 and k=500):
ic;n = 700;k = 500;nk = RecursiveFunctionTest(n, k);toc
Maximum recursion limit of 500 reached. Use set(0,'RecursionLimit',N) to change the limit. Be aware that exceeding your available stack space can
crash MATLAB and/or your computer.

tic;n = 700;k = 400;nk = RecursiveFunctionTest(n, k);toc
Elapsed time is 0.005635 seconds.
Very inefficient...

Measuring Matlab build in function nchoosek:
tic;nchoosek(1000000, 500000);toc
Warning: Result may not be exact. Coefficient is greater than 9.007199e+15 and is only accurate to 15 digits 
 In nchoosek at 92 
Elapsed time is 0.005081 seconds.

Conclusion:
You need to implement the C mex file without using recursion, and take a measure.

---

Measure without recursion:

```
static double factorial(double number) 
{
    int x;
    double fac = 1;

    if (number == 0)
    {
        return 1.0;
    }    

    for (x = 2; x <= (int)number; x++)
    {
        fac = fac * x;
    }

    return fac;
}



double choose(double n, double k)
{
    if (k == 0) 
    {
        return 1.0;
    }
    else
    {
        //n!/((n–k)! k!) 
        return factorial(n)/(factorial(n-k)*factorial(k));
    }
}
```

`tic;choose(1000000, 500000);toc`

> Elapsed time is 0.003079 seconds.

Faster...

Comment: Great answer. I want to use mex code because it is more faster than MATLAB file, although it may be a little less time. But when we use it in a loop (for), it is really useful. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

no need to mex binomial coefficients can be implemented in Matlab:

```
function nk=nchoosek2(n, k)
    if n-k > k
        nk = prod((k+1:n) .* prod((1:n-k).^ (-1/(n-k))));
    else
        nk = prod((n-k+1:n) .* prod((1:k).^ (-1/k)) ) ;
    end
end
```